# Test for last iteration of for loop in c#

Tags: c#

```c#
   public string GetUpgradesPurchasedVal()
   {
        string upgradesPurchasedVals = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < upgradesPurchased.Count; i++) {
            if (i == upgradesPurchased.Count) {
                upgradesPurchasedVals += upgradesPurchased [upgradeNames[i]].ToString () + "$";
            } else {
                upgradesPurchasedVals += upgradesPurchased [upgradeNames[i]].ToString () + "|";
            }
        }
        return upgradesPurchasedVals;
    }
```

So here I am looping through the `Dictionary<string,bool> upgradesPurchased` and I am trying to make sure if the `for` loop is at the last iteration marked by the line `if(i == upgradesPurchased.Count)` what I expected to happen in this case is if `i` is equal to the number of items in the dictionary then the string would receive a "$" at the end of it instead of a "|" however it would seem that the line is ignored altogether

Summary: I need to test if the `for` loop is at the last iteration if so then "$" should be added to the string if not "|" should be added to the string

Comment: Use ` == Count - 1` as Count is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a dictionary like this:

```
 Dictionary<string, bool> upgradesPurchased = new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
   {"Pentium 3", true},
   {"Core i9",   false},
   {"Abacus",    true},
 };
```

and you have a list

```
List<string> upgradeNames = new List<string>() {
  {"Pentium 3", "Core i9", "Abacus"},
};
```

And you want to obtain

```
true|false|true$
```

Here there's an *ambiguity* (*what* and *how* should we loop); however the main principle is the same: let .Net *do the work for you* (`String.Join`). In case you want to loop over the *dictionary* (but, please, notice that pairs in the dictionary don't have any order):

```
public string GetUpgradesPurchasedVal() {  
  return !upgradesPurchased.Any() 
    ? ""
    : string.Join("|", upgradesPurchased.Select(pair => pair.Value)) + "$";
}
```

In case you want to loop over the *list* (your current code):

```
public string GetUpgradesPurchasedVal() {  
  return !upgradesPurchased.Any() 
    ? ""
    : string.Join("|", upgradeNames.Select(name => upgradesPurchased[name])) + "$";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The loop condition is `i < upgradesPurchased.Count`, so clearly the condition in `if (i == upgradesPurchased.Count)` can never be true.

Since the iteration is zero-based, the last iteration would have `i == upgradesPurchased.Count - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i == upgradesPurchased.Count - 1)
```